# WordPress Adding a template via a plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm writing a plugin for a website, and one of the pages on the websites requires a custom template. How can I add a template via the plugin, without having to go into the theme's folder and adding it manually?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to change the existing theme you can always create a child theme: [Wordpress Codex: Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)